# How to calculate distance between two locations in SKMaps

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7, skmaps

I am using skobbler map framework.
In nearby search I am getting near places I need to get the distance of each locations from the current location by using Skobbler framework (with out using MapKit).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CLLocation object for this. This object provides the method:
 (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location.